# VBScript ODBC API reference

Tags: vbscript, reference, odbc

Does anyone know if there is a reference guide to Microsofts ODBC driver for Windows 7 / Server 2008?

I write VBScript code all the time access data via ODBC, but I can only find snippets of code from google searches.

I want to find out where I can find info about the api such as:

cursor information for:
objrs.open sql, 1,1
vs
objrs,open sql, 3,3

and:
I know there is a RecordCount property -> Is there a fieldcount property?
Is there a FieldName or FieldLabel property?

Where can I find the ODBC reference info for VBSCRIPT - not C?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [ADO documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not ODBC documentation.